# How to get status code from NSURLSessionDataTask?

Tags: ios, swift, afnetworking

In AFNetworking 3.0 some things was changed. Basicaly, there is no more operations, instead `session data tasks`. How can I get status code from `NSURLSessionDataTask`?

This is my block:

```
    GET("users/check_email", parameters: parameters, progress: nil, success: { sessionDataTask, response in

        // here I need status code of response

        }) { sessionDataTask, error in

            completionBlock(nil, NSError(sessionDataTask: sessionDataTask))
    }
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The `NSURLSessionDataTask` has a `response` property that can be cast to a `NSHTTPURLResponse` to get the status code:

Swift Example:

```
if let urlResponse = sessionDataTask.response as? NSHTTPURLResponse {
    let status = urlResponse.statusCode
}
```

Objective-C Example:

```
NSInteger statusCode = 0;

if ([sessionDataTask.response isKindOfClass:[NSHTTPURLResponse class]]) {
    NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)sessionDataTask.response;
    statusCode = httpResponse.statusCode;
}
```

Comment: it is not the same response, this is response from server, response inside `sessionDataTask` is response from http (headers and so on)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Better call `isKindOfClass` on `sessionDataTask.response`. Only if `YES` cast and get `statusCode`.

Comment: @meaning-matters, Sorry not quite sure what you mean, could you suggest an edit?

Answer (score 1):

`NSURLSessionDataTask` has `response` property, which will be populated with an object of `NSHTTPURLResponse` class, which has `statusCode` property.